# Learning React proof of concept

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am currently trying to teach myself React, I am working in codepen at the moment, what I am trying to do is create a simple user profile from a static piece of JSON.

What I want from someone is confirmation that my understanding is correct before I progress.

My understanding is that a React app is drive by the state object? Elements of this state object can be passed to components and they become props (which are read only?). If I can something in the state it will be reflected in any of the props used within components?

Here is my proof of concept so far, which is basically getting and avatar URL from state and creating a very simply avatar component to start with.

```
    /*
 * A simple React component
 */

const user = {
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "Anjela",
  "last_name": "Frow",
  "email": "afrow0@yelp.com",
  "dob": "1987-07-09",
  "gender": "Female",
  "avatar": "https://robohash.org/quaslaboriosamvoluptas.jpg?size=50x50&set=set1"
}

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      user:user
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (<Profile user={this.state.user} />);
  }
}

class Profile extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Avatar image={this.props.user.avatar} />
    )
  }
}

class Avatar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="avatar">
        <img src={this.props.image} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

https://codepen.io/87Development/pen/XabxGX?editors=1010

Comment: i will suggest you to check the [**DOC**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html) for that, it will cover all these things with details.

Comment: Wouldn't this rather be a question for codereview? React can be driven by either state or props, that's where you are correct in your assumptions :)

Comment: Yes. Your understanding is correct. You can pass states as a props to other components and that props updates only if you will update states of parent component

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try some stuff out and see how things "react".
For example, add a button which updates the `user.avatar`.

```
onClick() {
  this.setState({user: Object.assign({}, this.state.user, {avatar: 'new'})});
}
```

The `state.user` is hereby set to a completely different object reference which will cause a rerender.

You should see the updated `<Avatar />` as it receives its new props.

As you already mentioned `props` are readonly. `state` should also be considered readonly and never be updated direcly, but always through a `setState()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're right.

Although in your code, it's not very practical and "pure" to do this :

```
return (<Profile user={this.state.user} />);
```

The reason is because it means your `Profile` needs a full user object to be used, even though it actually only needs an image. So for reusability purposes and clarity, you could rather declare an avatar prop :

```
return (<Profile avatar={this.state.user.avatar} />);
```

With this you can use the `Profile` component even if you only have an avatar link.

That also means you should add a prop for every user property you wanna pass.